# Is Respond to invitations sent to another email address possible with Google Workspaces

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, google-calendar

I read about `Respond to invitations sent to another email address` [here](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37135). This sounds like I can send calendar responses from an email, I just have POP or SMTP access and not only my GMail address.

I now ask myself if this only works for GMail or also the Google Workspace offering?
Does anybody know?

Comment: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/